# Getting the Android camera folder before API 8

Tags: android, camera, environment, android-camera

In Android 2.2 and newer, you can get the default camera folder using Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM, but is there a way to get it in Android 2.1 and earlier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, sorry. You can try:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM")
```

and see how stable that is.

Bear in mind that neither my technique nor `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` will necessarily be honored by all devices. When the Android documentation refers to `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` as the "*traditional* location for pictures and videos when mounting the device as a camera" (emphasis mine), a warning bell should be going off in your mind. Just because it is "traditional" does not mean any device manufacturer will necessarily use it.

Comment: Thanks, CW. I needed to ignore that folder in my code, so I guess I'll just do a check to see if "DCIM" is included in the absolute file path.

Comment: @Michell Bak: That's probably a reasonable test, though that too isn't exactly a guarantee. OTOH, I can't think of a better test, and since it's the sort of thing that various desktop software expects, it's hopefully pretty common.